# CONVERT_TZ not working

Tags: mysql

We have a script to run through PHP myAdmin, as follows:

```
UPDATE utilities_alert SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','00:00');
UPDATE utilities_update SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','00:00');
UPDATE utilities_assetlocation SET start=CONVERT_TZ(start,'-06:00','00:00');
UPDATE utilities_assetlocation SET end=CONVERT_TZ(end,'-06:00','00:00');
UPDATE utilities_idlelog SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','00:00');
```

It's not working and returning NULL values. Then I came across this

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/populate-time-zone-data-for-mysql.html

, followed all the steps and to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There may well be a bug in this verb, I spent some time getting very frustrated trying this. However I did get it to work if I used this format.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(TimeSeen, 'America/New_York','Europe/London');
```

Where TimeSeen was a DateTime field.

If you have loaded the timezone data as you say, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I forgot a + sign.

It should be:

```
UPDATE utilities_alert SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','+00:00');
UPDATE utilities_update SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','+00:00');
UPDATE utilities_assetlocation SET start=CONVERT_TZ(start,'-06:00','+00:00');
UPDATE utilities_assetlocation SET end=CONVERT_TZ(end,'-06:00','+00:00');
UPDATE utilities_idlelog SET date=CONVERT_TZ(date,'-06:00','+00:00');
```